# The probability that no player is dealt a blackjack in a 4-players scenario

Tags: probability, card-games

The problem that both you and the dealer are not dealt the blackjack can be solved by finding the probability that at least 1 player is dealt a blackjack and then use the law of total probability to find the probability that no one is dealt a blackjack. This approach is stated here [Blackjack Probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1141579/blackjack-probability)).

Now we have 4 players and we want to find the probability that nobody is dealt a blackjack. I wonder if there is a simpler approach than calculating 1 - \sum P(only i player is dealt a blackjack) where i = 1 to 4 since it is more complicated to calculate when i = 3 and 4.

Comment: Unsure if the following approach is simpler.  I would use Inclusion-Exclusion.  See [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) for an 
introduction to Inclusion-Exclusion.
Then, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4427605/inclusion-exclusion-principle-what-is-1n1/4427645#4427645) for an explanation of and justification for the Inclusion-Exclusion *formula*.  Using the syntax of the second link, for $~k \in \{1,2,3,4\},~$ I would let $~S_k~$ denote the subset of all possible deals where Person$-k~$ was dealt a blackjack.

Comment: Re last comment, note that when enumerating (for example) $~S_1 \cap S_2,~$ you have to compute the number of ways that Person$-2~$ could be dealt blackjack, **given** that Person$-1~$ was dealt blackjack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this using [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle):

$$
1 
- \binom{4}{1} \frac{\frac{4!}{3!} \frac{16!}{15!}} {\binom{52}{2}}
+ \binom{4}{2} \frac{\frac{4!}{2!} \frac{16!}{14!}} {\binom{52}{2}\binom{50}{2}}
- \binom{4}{3} \frac{\frac{4!}{1!} \frac{16!}{13!}} {\binom{52}{2}\binom{50}{2}\binom{48}{2}}
+ \binom{4}{4} \frac{\frac{4!}{0!} \frac{16!}{12!}} {\binom{52}{2}\binom{50}{2}\binom{48}{2}\binom{46}{2}}
$$

where in each term:

- The leading coefficient is the number of ways to select $i$ out of the 4 players to definitely have blackjack (the non-selected players may or may not have blackjack).
- The first factor in the numerator is the number of ways in which 1 of the 4 aces can be assigned to each of the $i$ selected players.
- The second factor in the numerator is the number of ways in which 1 of the 16 ten-value cards can be assigned to each of the $i$ selected players.
- The denominator is the number of ways to deal 2 cards to each of the $i$ selected players.

You can confirm this using my [Icepool Python package](https://github.com/HighDiceRoller/icepool), which is not as computationally efficient but requires less manual work:

```
from icepool import Deck, multiset_function

deck = Deck([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10] * 4)

@multiset_function
def blackjack4(a, b, c, d):
    return a >= [1, 10], b >= [1, 10], c >= [1, 10], d >= [1, 10]

output(blackjack4(deck.deal(2, 2, 2, 2)).map(sum))
```

This computes the chance of $i$ hands drawing a 2-card blackjack. The chance of $i = 0$ is

$$
\frac{1550115663120}{1896396138000} \approx 81.74\%
$$

[You can run this in your browser here.](https://highdiceroller.github.io/icepool/apps/icecup.html?c=GYJw9gtgBAlgxgUwA5jAG1hFIAuUAiCcA1gDRQQCuaOMAzgjgPrCUB2ctYbAUDwCZFiUALwEhACgDaARnIAmcgGZyAFnIBWcgDZyAdnIAOcgE5yMgAzmrUS9YC6UAFRRVASj4ABKjXqMW7Jww3AIIwFAARmgAhiQAVrHEqhLR5BHkcOT8bgBcPFAFUCCMlCBsUNFQAHxisg5p1bVythb2GY1QdS1tUPwdXZb2fGCUOEijElGJCSTJgiQAdILRaBKKUOubbm4LENFIEnSUENs8QA)

Comment: Beat me to it :D! But I'm getting a slightly different answer $\frac{2152938421}{2633883525}$ although our formulas should be the same. I used this Sage-code to calculate: https://www.online-python.com/0LCxrgPR7D

Comment: It's just a matter of simplifying fractions or not. I chose to keep the raw denominator of the 4-way deal.